# 門前払いを受けている expression

Tags: words, expressions

> 「ふむ。どうやら宴もたけなわというところだな。こんなところで**門前払いを受けている**場合ではないぞ、セイバー」

I know the expression:

> 門前払いを喰わせる=To slam the door in one's face

But I can't find anything on this.

I think it means something like:
To accept an uninvited guest.

My TL:

> It looks like the banquet it's at its peak.
>   This is not the time to accept an uninvited guest, Saber

Answer (score 3, accepted):

門前【もんぜん】払【ばら】い is a fixed noun phrase meaning "turning down without serious consideration, interview and/or review." There are some variations regarding the verb choice:

- **to reject**: 門前払いする・門前払いにする・門前払いを食らわせる
- **to be rejected**: 門前払いされる・門前払いにされる・門前払いを食らう・門前払いを受ける

This 受ける simply means "to get" as in "get punched," "get ignored," etc.

So 「こんなところで門前払いを受けている場合ではないぞ」 means "You're not supposed to be rejected/ignored/etc in a place like this."